# pointer to an int array gives the same address as when it is dereferenced

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-address, dereference

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int g[] = {9,8};
    int (*j)[2] = &g;
    cout << "*(j):" << *(j) << endl;
    cout << "j:" << j << endl;
    cout << "&j:" << &j << endl;
    cout << "&(*j)" << &(*j) << endl;
    cout << "*(*j):" << *(*j) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

which ouputs:

```
*(j):0x7fff5ab37c7c
j:0x7fff5ab37c7c
&j:0x7fff5ab37c70
&(*j)0x7fff5ab37c7c
*(*j):9
```

I think that j is a pointer to an array of two integer.

And &g is the address of the whole array.

Then j store the address of the whole array.

And so I use the *(j), it will dereference the first element in the array.

But the result said that *(j) store the array address the same value as j.

I cannot figure out how this happened.

Comment: `*j` is the array itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"I think that `j` is a pointer to an array"*

***Yes, it is***. And that's also the reason why `*j` output the same address as outputting `g` would do. In this case an array decays into the pointer and that's why even outputting `j` yields the same result.

The fact that the same address is outputted might make you think that `j` and `*j` are the same pointers, however they are not. Their ***type*** is different (a fact that actually matters):

```
int g[] = {9,8};     // int[]
int (*j)[2] = &g;    // int (*)[2]
```

so using `*j` becomes equivalent to using `g` directly, just like `*(*j)` becomes equivalent to `*g`.
And `&(*j)` is nothing but `j`, which is initialized with <s>an address of an array</s> (an address taken from decayed `g`, i.e. an address of the first element of this array).

So why `j` and `*j` outputs the same address and `*(*j)` outputs the value of first element?

Because of the type of `j` being `int (*)[2]`. A simple example:

```
int g[] = {9,8};
int (*j)[2] = &g;     // j points to the first element as well
cout << *((int*) j);
```

outputs `9`.

Answer (score 3):

> I think that j is a pointer to an array of two integer.
>   And &g is the address of the whole array.

That is correct.

> And so I use the *(j), it will dereference the first element in the array.

This is not. `*j` gives you the array itself. When you insert it to `cout`, it decays to a pointer again (this time to a pointer to its first element, type `int*`) and its value is printed.

It's in effect the same as if you wrote `cout << g`.